# How to crawl through pages using Simple HTML DOM php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

I am collecting data from [this page](http://jobs.bdjobs.com/jobsearch.asp?fcatId=-1). I am using Simple HTML DOM parser. I want to collect data from the next pages. The problem is there is no new link for next pages so I can not loop through the links. I guess it is done by Javascript. How do I go to next pages and collect data from there?

```
    `// array to store scraped links
    $links = array();  
    // crawl the webpage for links
    foreach($html->find("a") as $link){
        array_push($links, $link->href);
    }`
```

with the above code I only find the links that is on the page. but the page numbers 1,2,3 ... does not have a link.

Comment: Can you show us the codes please ?

Comment: We need to know, what have you tried till now?

Comment: // array to store scraped links

$links = array();
// crawl the webpage for links
foreach($html->find("a") as $link){
   array_push($links, $link->href);
} 

this finds the links that is on the page. but the page numbers 1,2,3,4,5 does not have a valid link.

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use PhantomJS / CasperJS for this task? They're very good for simulating user requests and scraping web pages.